# Create angular promise with another value

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have a web service which returns some data. To prevent code duplication I want to move http request call to angular service:

```
angular.module('abc', [])
    .factory('def', function () {
        return {
            getData: function () {
                return $http.post('/path/', {});
            }
        };
    });
```

All is good, but necessary data is inside complicated object, and I have to write every time:

```
def.getData().then(function (response) {
    scope.obj = response.data.qwe.rty.xyz;
});
```

What is the easiest way to return promise, which will send value of `response.data.qwe.rty.xyz` directly to `successCallback`? And I can write like this:

```
def.getData().then(function (obj) {
    scope.obj = obj;
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call `$http.post('/path/', {})` returns a promise on which you then call `then()`. Note that `then()` also returns a promise, so you can chain the calls. Your code could therefore look like this:

```
angular.module('abc', [])
    .factory('def', function () {
        return {
            getData: function () {
                return $http.post('/path/', {})
                        .then(function(response) {
                            return response.data.qwe.rty.xyz;
                        });
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the deferring behavior that implemented in the `$q` provider

like so :

```
angular.module('abc', [])
.factory('def', function ($q) {

    return {
        getData: function () {
             var def = $q.defer
             $http.post('/path/', {}).then(function(response){
               def.resolve(response.data.qwe.rty.xyz)
             });
            return def.promise; 
        }
    };
});
```

and use it in your controller like :

```
def.getData().then(function (response) {
 scope.obj = response;
});
```